# Sort list of nested dictionaries by multiple attributes

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

i have my sample data as

```
b = [{"id": 1, "name": {"d_name": "miranda", "ingredient": "orange"}, "score": 1.123},
 {"id": 20, "name": {"d_name": "limca", "ingredient": "lime"}, "score": 4.231},
 {"id": 3, "name": {"d_name": "coke", "ingredient": "water"}, "score": 4.231},
 {"id": 2, "name": {"d_name": "fanta", "ingredient": "water"}, "score": 4.231},
 {"id": 3, "name": {"d_name": "dew", "ingredient": "water & sugar"}, "score": 2.231}]
```

i need to sort such that `score ASC, name DESC, id ASC` (by relational db notation).
So far, i have implemented

```
def sort_func(e):
    return (e['score'], e['name']['d_name'], e['id'])

a = b.sort(key=sort_func, reverse=False)
```

This works for `score ASC, name ASC, id ASC`.
but for `score ASC, name DESC, id ASC` if i try to sort by `name DESC` it throws error. because of `unary - error` in `-e['name']['d_name']`.

How can i approach this problem, from here ? Thanks,

Edit 1:
i need to make this dynamic such that there can be case such as `e['name'['d_name'] ASC, e['name']['ingredient'] DESC`. How can i handle this type of dynamic behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by `-score`, `name`, `-id` with `reverse=True`:

```py
from pprint import pprint


b = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": {"d_name": "miranda", "ingredient": "orange"},
        "score": 1.123,
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "name": {"d_name": "limca", "ingredient": "lime"},
        "score": 4.231,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": {"d_name": "coke", "ingredient": "water"},
        "score": 4.231,
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": {"d_name": "fanta", "ingredient": "water"},
        "score": 4.231,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": {"d_name": "dew", "ingredient": "water & sugar"},
        "score": 2.231,
    },
]

pprint(
    sorted(
        b,
        key=lambda k: (-k["score"], k["name"]["d_name"], -k["id"]),
        reverse=True,
    )
)
```

Prints:

```py
[{'id': 1,
  'name': {'d_name': 'miranda', 'ingredient': 'orange'},
  'score': 1.123},
 {'id': 3,
  'name': {'d_name': 'dew', 'ingredient': 'water & sugar'},
  'score': 2.231},
 {'id': 20, 'name': {'d_name': 'limca', 'ingredient': 'lime'}, 'score': 4.231},
 {'id': 2, 'name': {'d_name': 'fanta', 'ingredient': 'water'}, 'score': 4.231},
 {'id': 3, 'name': {'d_name': 'coke', 'ingredient': 'water'}, 'score': 4.231}]
```

Comment: Thanks, @andrej, this works for this case. I am need to make this dynamic, user can select more than one string value to sort such that,  `e['name']['d_name'] ASC ,e['name']['ingredient'] DESC` , How can solve this ?

Comment: @Ansuman You can sort in multiple steps: First sort by score DESC, then sort by name ASC, then sort by id DESC. Python sort is *stable* so it will work.